# How is security implemented in an ASP.NET MVC REST API application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api, security

I was reading here,

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/01/20/restful-api-with-aspnet50.html

but I am missing how to do security.

What security model is used for an API?

Do I give a consumer a generated "key"?

Windows Authentication?

Mobile?

Comment: There are tons of different ways you can go about implementing security in a REST API. ASP.NET MVC has ways to implement whatever form of security you want to use, but it doesn't provide a way itself because that's not its main responsibility. One good way might be to use OpenID Connect, for which [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) provides a good way to get started.

Comment: You are talking about authentication. "Security" in an application or API (eg. .NET MVC or WebAPI) is much more than that. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) is a good resource on how to write secure software.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this [blog post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) to be very helpful when implementing security for Web API. Look at Owin token based authentication first. The blog describes usage with AngularJS but the client could be anything including mobile.